# target location after pressing enter

Tags: javascript, css, html, samsung-smart-tv

This is probably a very simple thing, but I'm very new to Javascript and HTML5 and can't seem to find an answer to my question.

I'm currently developing an app for Samsung Smart TV.

I currently have 2 major files: `Main.js` and `index.html`, in which most of my code is written. Also, I have a style sheet called `Main.css`.

My problem: I have a button the screen, that when pressing it (that is, when pushing enter on the remote), I want the screen to change in to a completely different one (from welcome screen to admin settings). How do I do that??

Hope my question is not too general. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location

Comment: please don't use window.location on Samsung Smart TV Platform, It will cause all your data lost since the javascript variable not passed to other page

Answer (score 1):

You should divide your index.html with divs that represent a scene. To make it easy please use Basic Project it will generate a pattern to split the html/css/js like different pages and you only need to call `sf.scene.show("SettingsScene")`

If you're using javascript project, then the answer from `user3384518` is the only way. Like i mentioned above, split your body to several divs and do hide/show the div

Answer (score 0):

Your question is clear, but you don't say if you use a library (or not).

So, if you use jQuery :

```
$('.myButtonName').click(function () {
    $('#myWelcomScreenDiv').hide(200, function () {
        $('#myAdminSettingsDiv').show(200);
    });
});
```

But, if you would like to do something better, I recommend you to use a framework like Backbone.js or Angular.js.